# Can I flatten a List<object> to an anonymous object with properties for each item?

Tags: c#, linq, list, anonymous-types

I am trying flatten a list of objects into an annonymous objects.

For example lets say i have:

```
List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
tags.Add(new Tag(id: "Tag1", value:true));
tags.Add(new Tag(id: "Tag2", value:true));
tags.Add(new Tag(id: "Tag3", value:false));
```

I would then like to flatten this list to an anonymous object like:

```
tags.Select(x => new
{
    Tag1 = true,
    Tag2 = true,
    Tag3 = false
}
```

is what I am trying to do possible on a bigger / more generic scale?

Comment: If you do not strongly-type the properties, then you will not be able to access them as so... in which case, you might as well just have a `Dictionary<string, bool>` or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes using an [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var o = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string,object>;

o.Add("Tag1", true);
o.Add("Tag2", true);
o.Add("Tag3", false);
```

In this way you are actually adding properties to the ExpandoObject

Comment: Is this possible to do in a `Select` or `SelectMany` so I can do it on a bigger / more generic scale?

Comment: @user1: See my answer for that, though I assume you knew how to do it by hand. I thought this answer was awesome, but I am not sure if it's needed for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to *flatten* something, but rather to turn your list into a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> = tags.ToDictionary(tag => tag.id, tag => tag.value);
```

---

I'm not really sure what you mean with "a bigger/more generic scale", maybe you can edit your question and add a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with this hack using json.net ... I don't think it's as useful but just to demo that it is possible ...

```
dynamic theflat =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
                                              $"{{{tags.Select( x => $"\"{x.ID}\":\"{x.Value}\"" ).Aggregate( ( p, n ) => $"{p},{n}" )}}}" );
        ;
```

The code creates a json serialized version of all the tags, and then deserializes them as a dynamic. you can test it out as :

```
        Console.WriteLine(theflat.Tag1); //true
        Console.WriteLine( theflat.Tag2 ); //true
        Console.WriteLine( theflat.Tag3 ); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do what you want (I upvoted the accepted answer, but I actually don't think you need to do it that way. I made you a [FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EzQHhA)

```
            List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>()
            {
                new Tag(id: "Tag1", val:true),
                new Tag(id: "Tag2", val:true),
                new Tag(id: "Tag3", val:false)
            };

            var dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>(); 

            foreach(Tag tag in tags)
            {   
                dict.Add(tag.Id, tag.Val); 
            }
```